# .on() method child selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple range inputs on one page and I want the output of each range to update in real time to a specific element: so the first feedback slider would output its value to the  with id "feedbackOne" and the second feedback slider would  output its value to "feedbackTwo". Currently, nothing seems to be happening, but if I change my function to look like this:

```
var outputOne = document.querySelectorAll("output")[0];

$(document).on("input", "input['type=range']", function(x)
  {
    outputOne.innerHTML = x.currentTarget.value;
  });
```

Then of course the output from the first slider works, but is influenced also by the second slider.

```js
$(function()
{
  //Query DOM for specific <output> elements
  var outputOne = document.querySelectorAll("#feedbackOne")[0];
  var outputTwo = document.querySelectorAll("#feedbackTwo")[0];
  //Dynamically update DOM with output value
  $(document).on("input", "feedbackSliderOne", function(x)
  {
    outputOne.innerHTML = x.currentTarget.value;
  });

  $(document).on("input", "feedbackSliderTwo", function(y)
  {
    outputOne.innerHTML = y.currentTarget.value;
  });
});
```

```css
#feedbackSliderContainer
{
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

#feedbackOne
{
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  color: #58a7dd;
}

#feedbackTwo
{
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  color: #58a7dd;
}

#feedbackFirst
{
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

#feedbackSecond
{
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  width: 100%;
}

.easy
{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.hard
{
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="feedbackSliderContainer">
    <!--Feedback One-->
    <output id="feedbackOne">2</output>
    <div id="feedbackFirst">
       <input type="range" id="feedBackSliderOne" class="ranger" min="0" value="2" max="4" />
      <div class="easy">EASY</div>
      <div class="hard">HARD</div>
    </div>
    <!--Feedback Two-->
    <output id="feedbackTwo">2</output>
    <div id="feedbackSecond">
      <input type="range" id="feedBackSliderTwo" class="ranger" min="0" value="2" max="4" />
      <div class="easy">TOO<br />SLOW</div>
      <div class="hard" style="top: -35px;">TOO <br />FAST</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't use IDs to find the target elements, use the DOM structure. From the input, go up to the parent div, and from there to the previous sibling.

Comment: So are you saying I should target "feedbackFirst"?

Comment: I'm saying stop thinking IDs were the only way to select elements ...

Comment: Thank you, I know this, I am just not sure how it applies here. Although @cars10m posted a really interesting answer using *with* and *this*, hadn't thought about those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues with your code:

selector using id returns a single element, not an array.
`$(document).on("input", "feedbackSliderOne", function(x)`, that selector will not work there is not tag named `feedbackSliderOne`, you need to give some id like `#feedBackSliderOne`.

```js
$(function()
{
  //Query DOM for specific <output> elements
  var outputOne = $("#feedbackOne");
  var outputTwo = $("#feedbackTwo");
  //Dynamically update DOM with output value
  $(document).on("input", "#feedBackSliderOne", function(x)
  {
    outputOne.text(x.currentTarget.value);
  });

  $(document).on("input", "#feedBackSliderTwo", function(y)
  {
    outputTwo.text(y.currentTarget.value);
  });
});
```

```css
#feedbackSliderContainer
{
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

#feedbackOne
{
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  color: #58a7dd;
}

#feedbackTwo
{
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  color: #58a7dd;
}

#feedbackFirst
{
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

#feedbackSecond
{
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  width: 100%;
}

.easy
{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.hard
{
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="feedbackSliderContainer">
    <!--Feedback One-->
    <output id="feedbackOne">2</output>
    <div id="feedbackFirst">
       <input type="range" id="feedBackSliderOne" class="ranger" min="0" value="2" max="4" />
      <div class="easy">EASY</div>
      <div class="hard">HARD</div>
    </div>
    <!--Feedback Two-->
    <output id="feedbackTwo">2</output>
    <div id="feedbackSecond">
      <!--<p id="feedTwo"></p>-->
      <input type="range" id="feedBackSliderTwo" class="ranger" min="0" value="2" max="4" />
      <div class="easy">TOO<br />SLOW</div>
      <div class="hard" style="top: -35px;">TOO <br />FAST</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works and helped me understand the *.on()* method better!

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simpe! You really only need to write the following JavaScript

```
$(function()
{
  $(document).on("change", 'input[type=range]', function()
  { 
    with($(this)) parent().prev().text(val());
  });
});
```

and everything should work out fine. This assumes a certain structure in your html. To make it more flexible you could turn the `parent()` into `closest()` and make it more specific.

The `.on()` event listener is set up to listen for all incoming 'input' events on any input element of type 'range'. It will do its work relative to the input element concerned. There is no need to fiddle around with unwieldy Ids.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$(document).on("click", "#feedBackSliderOne", function(x) {` and also I have merged your `click` events into one:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#feedBackSliderOne, #feedBackSliderTwo", function(x) {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'feedBackSliderOne')
      $("#feedbackOne").text(x.currentTarget.value);
    else
      $("#feedbackTwo").text(x.currentTarget.value);
  });
});
```

```css
#feedbackSliderContainer {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

#feedbackOne {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  color: #58a7dd;
}

#feedbackTwo {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  color: #58a7dd;
}

#feedbackFirst {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

#feedbackSecond {
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  width: 100%;
}

.easy {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.hard {
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="feedbackSliderContainer">
  <!--Feedback One-->
  <output id="feedbackOne">2</output>
  <div id="feedbackFirst">
    <input type="range" id="feedBackSliderOne" class="ranger" min="0" value="2" max="4" />
    <div class="easy">EASY</div>
    <div class="hard">HARD</div>
  </div>
  <!--Feedback Two-->
  <output id="feedbackTwo">2</output>
  <div id="feedbackSecond">
    <!--<p id="feedTwo"></p>-->
    <input type="range" id="feedBackSliderTwo" class="ranger" min="0" value="2" max="4" />
    <div class="easy">TOO<br />SLOW</div>
    <div class="hard" style="top: -35px;">TOO <br />FAST</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but the snippet does not seem to work in my browser.

Comment: What browser are you using and what error are you seeing in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("input", "#feedbackFirst input[type='range']", function(x)
{
    outputOne.innerHTML = x.currentTarget.value;
});

$(document).on("input", "#feedbackSecond input[type='range']", function(y)
{
    outputTwo.innerHTML = y.currentTarget.value;
});
```